# Changing Datepicker format to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

The default UI datepicker result is mm/dd/yyyy, and I need it to be dd/mm/yyyy. I tried any solution people adviced but nothing works.
Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartingDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+4Y",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#EndingDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#EndingDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+4Y",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            $("#StartingDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)

        }
    });
});
```

At the moment both Datepickers give me mm/dd/yyyy. I already tried this: `$('#StartingDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });` but it didn't work.
I also tried to add `dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"` like that:

```
        ...
        $("#StartingDate").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+4Y",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            ....
```

but is still mm/dd/yyyy.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what does ASP.net have to do with this question?

Comment: What datepicker are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, it has nothing to do with ASP.net. I'm using UI datepicker, post updated

Comment: Does this help? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: I already tried the examples they give, it doesn't work. maybe I don't place it right in the code. if someone can show me where to put it on my code it would be great.

Comment: If the datepicker works then it's more likely a configuration problem. Look at my answer, it might help you.

Comment: Why do you need 'onSelect'-event ?

Comment: It validates that Starting date is not after Ending date and the opposite. Your solution works perfect, I was pretty sure I already tried it, but now it works!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this JSFiddle and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/rh4kza89/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="DatepickerDiv">
    <input id="StartingDate"></input>
    <input id="EndingDate"></input>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#StartingDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+4Y",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});

$("#EndingDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+4Y",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

Try using simple parameters when initalizing the datepicke and add the parameters step by step.

Answer (score 0):

try $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy");